# Put a mathematical formula in the middle of a new sentence in LaTeX

Tags: latex, formula, inline

I wrote down the following mathematical formula, and before it I defined it in some sentences. I would like to put this mathematical formula in the middle of a sentence. How is it possible to do this in LaTeX?

```
${( \,{Y}) \,}\equiv H[ \,{{p}( \,{y}) \,}] \,=\sum_{y} {p( \,{y})\: \\log \,{p( \,{y}) \,}}$
```

[image]

Actually, as you can see in the above equation is located at the left side of the sentence, I would like to shift it at the center of the sentence. I tried to use `\hspace{3cm}` to move it to right, but I would like to know a general way, because I should write down many formulas in one page and I would like to see all of them at the center of each sentence and aligned also I would like to specify each equation by specific number. However, the `\begin{equation}` will give a number to each equation automatically

Comment: I do not understand your problem. Can you clarify what you mean by "at the center of a sentence". Otherwise, you can just past you formula $...$ where you want.

Comment: Maybe not "inline" as you tagged? Using $$ ... $$ instead of the single dollars $ ... $ as delimiters for your equation? In this case, try both leaving a blank line before and after it in the code and not leaving them, for two different vertical spacing. Otherwise update your question with further details  :)

Comment: @AlainMerigot, thanks for your response, actually, as you can see in the above equation is located at the left side of the sentence, I would like to shift it at the center of the sentence. I tried to use \hspace{3cm} to move it to right, but I would like to know a general way, because I should write down many formulas in one page and I would like to see all of them at the center of each sentence and aligned also I would like to specify each equation by specific number. However, the \begin{equatio} will give a number to each equation automatically.

Comment: @Pouyi Hi! Remember to mark any of the three answers below as accepted, if it solves! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having difficulty visualizing how you want to center the mathematical formulas in the middle of each sentence because sentences have variable lengths resulting in a jumbled page layout that is harmful to readability. A cleaner way of doing it would by to center the mathematical formulas in the center of new lines. If it was my page I would probably do both on the same page. Sometimes I want to position an equation in the exact center of a new line in order to give it focus, otherwise I want to position the rest of the equations inline in order to improve readability. There's no reason why you can't do both, and a granular approach gives you the most control over the page's layout.

Insert the LaTeX equation anywhere in a sentence as HTML or markdown. A pair of `<sub> </sub>` HTML tags is used to format the y subscript that goes after the sigma character. Markdown also supports the `<sub>` tag.

```
(Y) ≡ H[p(y)] = Σyp(y)log p(y)
```

I suppose there are websites for converting LaTeX code to other formats, but the method I use is to convert from LaTeX to an image in a word processor by following the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859923/inserting-a-math-equation-to-a-libreoffice-presentation/859929#859929) and then manually type the plain text that's in the image. Another way to do it is with the [KLatexFormula](https://klatexformula.sourceforge.io/downloads) open source app. I searched Wikipedia for the triple bar character and sigma character that are seen in the above mathematical formula.

[image]
<sup>**KLatexFormula**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**KLatexFormula preview**</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I read your comment to the question and I can confirm what I wrote into mine. Further, you have several choices for the delimiters if you want centered but not labeled math:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$$A=A$$

\[B=B\]

\begin{displaymath}
C=C
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

This is the proper way, instead of approximating centering using `\hspace` command.

Also, if you want: [**a further reading**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/what-are-the-differences-between-align-equation-and-displaymath).

Comment: You should not use `$$...$$` in latex, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503 for more information

Comment: True, the second and third way should be preferred :)

Answer (score 0):

Set your math equations inside `\[`...`\]`. This will centre them horizontally as a display and leave them unnumbered. If you want to add a number manually, you can use `\tag{<stuff>}` (which can be `\label`ed and referenced later using `\eqref`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam posuere maximus diam sed mattis. 
Curabitur non ultrices orci, sit amet placerat nibh. Quisque in urna in erat convallis ultrices. 
Aliquam arcu diam, scelerisque in tellus sit amet, sollicitudin lobortis lacus. Nulla ut sapien 
in lacus consectetur maximus.
\[
  (Y) \equiv H[ p(y) ] = \sum_y p(y) \log p(y)
\]
Maecenas vitae purus vitae dolor porttitor molestie. Nulla gravida, 
odio vitae congue venenatis, mi eros feugiat justo, quis rutrum mi ipsum at odio. Pellentesque 
pharetra arcu sapien, feugiat lacinia arcu finibus at. Maecenas scelerisque risus sed imperdiet 
venenatis. Proin pretium varius tellus luctus egestas. Maecenas risus felis, laoreet vitae mauris 
viverra, dignissim rutrum nulla.
\[
  (Y) \equiv H[ p(y) ] = \sum_y p(y) \log p(y) \tag{x.y}\label{eqn:x-y}
\]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam posuere maximus diam sed mattis. 
Curabitur non ultrices orci, sit amet placerat nibh. Quisque in urna in erat convallis ultrices. 
Aliquam arcu diam, scelerisque in tellus sit amet, sollicitudin lobortis lacus. Nulla ut sapien 
in lacus consectetur maximus. \eqref{eqn:x-y}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. It didn't work for me. when I define it with {equation} it gives me a number for equation but my problem was to find a way to shift the equation to the center while using \begin{define}